# Glide: Resize ImageView to fit image in glide, not the other way around

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a recycler view where cells contain an ImageView. I'd like the cells to match_parent width (the screen width), but expand height wise as needed and keep aspect ratio (wrap_content). The problem is that Glide will resize the image to match the placeholder image or (when reusing a cell) match whichever the previous image size was. Is there a way I can tell Glide to get the native image size, every time? I don't want the image to resize, I want the imageview to resize.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Be sure to include a compete minimal code example so we can see what you are trying to accomplish.